# What is the correct way to compute a Kullback–Leibler metric?

Tags: probability-distributions, matlab

If you go to the [Wikipedia page for Kullback-Leibler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) and scroll down to the definitions section you will see:

$D_{KL}(p||q)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}p(x)log(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)})$

for two arbitrary probability density functions $p(x) $ and $q(x)$.

If you go to the [Wikipedia page for Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and go to the bottom of the column on the right you will see somebody has done the hard work of plugging in the PDF for a univariate Gaussian distribution for the specific case when $p(x)$ is $N(\mu_0,\sigma_0)$ and $q(x)$ is $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$. The Kullback-Leibler distance measure is then given to be:

$D_{KL}(N_0,N_1)=\frac{1}{2}( \frac{\sigma_0}{\sigma_1})^2+  \frac{(\mu_1-\mu_0)^2 }{\sigma_1^2}-1+2ln(\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_0})   )$

I tried to code both of these into MATLAB and run a simple test with $\mu_0=1, \sigma_0=1$ and $\mu_1=3, \sigma_1=1$.

However, for some reason both of these Kullback-Leibler functions give me different values. So I am wondering if there is something wrong in my code or are these two KL distances (one from the Normal Distribution wiki page and the other from the Kullback-Leibler wiki page) are actually supposed to be different?

Here is my MATLAB code:

```
function [ distance ] = KL(mu1,sigma1,mu2, sigma2 )
% define the two guassian PDFs with their corresponding mu and sigma values
fun1 = @(x) (1/( sigma1*sqrt(2*pi)  )  )*exp(1/2* (-(x-mu1).^2)/(sigma1^2));
fun2 = @(x) (1/( sigma2*sqrt(2*pi)  )  )*exp(1/2* (-(x-mu2).^2)/(sigma2^2));

% implement the integrand of the KL integral from the "Kullback-Leibler"
% wiki page
fun3 = @(x) fun1(x)*log(fun1(x)/fun2(x))
fun4 = @(x) fun2(x)*log(fun2(x)/fun1(x))

y=inf; % integrate from - infinity to infinity
distance = integral(fun3, -y,y) + integral(fun4, -y,y);

% implement the KL defined in the "Normal Distribution" wiki page
dist2 = (sigma1/sigma2)^2 + (mu1-mu2)^2/(sigma2^2)-1+2*log(sigma2/sigma1);

dist4 = 1/2 * (dist2)

% It should be that dist4 = distance (but it is not the case. Why?
```

Here is the output for a simple example with $\mu_0=1, \sigma_0=1$ and $\mu_1=3, \sigma_1=1$.

```
>> KL(1,1,3,1)

dist4 =

     2


distance =

    0.1080
```

Shouldn't they both be the same? If not, which one should I use?

Comment: Your `distance` seem to compute not the KL-divergence $D(\mathcal{N}_0||\mathcal{N}_1)$, but rather its symmetrized version $D(\mathcal{N}_0||\mathcal{N}_1) + D(\mathcal{N}_1||\mathcal{N}_0)$. This does not fully resolve the mystery, howwever, since the correct answer for this symmetrized version for your parameters is actually $2+2=4$ and not $0.1080$. Just for reference, *Mathematica 11* yields 2 for both the integral definition and the formula described in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Yes, I added in the symmetrized version, but even if I remove the symmetric part both answers are still different. So are you suggesting "2" is probably the correct answer?

Comment: Indeed. I humbly suspect that the discrepancy might be a consequence of accumulated rounding error, although I have little exposure to MATLAB to tell for sure. Addendum: If $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$, then \begin{align*}D(X_0||X_1)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_0}(x)\left[\log\left(\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_0}\right)-\frac{(x-\mu_0)^2}{2\sigma_0^2}+\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\\&=\log\left(\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_0}\right)-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2}\mathbf{E}[(X_0-\mu_1)^2],\end{align*} which simplifies to the formula in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Got it, thanks.